# TaskID.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskType;I)V

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

```
val jobConf = new JobConf(hbaseConf)  
jobConf.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])  
jobConf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tablename)  

val indataRDD = sc.makeRDD(Array("1,jack,15","2,Lily,16","3,mike,16"))  

indataRDD.map(_.split(','))   
val rdd = indataRDD.map(_.split(',')).map{arr=>{  
val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(arr(0).toInt))  
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes(arr(1)))  
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("age"),Bytes.toBytes(arr(2).toInt))  
(new ImmutableBytesWritable, put)   
}}  
  rdd.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf)
```

When I run hadoop or spark jobs, I often meet the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskID.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobID;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskType;I)V
at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.setIDs(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.preSetup(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1188)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1161)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1161)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1161)
at com.iteblog.App$.main(App.scala:62)
at com.iteblog.App.main(App.scala)`
```

At the begin, I think, is the jar conflict, but I carefully checked the jar: there are no other jars. The spark and hadoop versions are:

```
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1</version>`

<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
<version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.5.0</version>
```

And I found that the TaskID and TaskType are all in the **hadoop-core** jar, but not in the same package. Why the mapred.TaskID can refer the mapreduce.TaskType ?

Comment: What hadoop are you running this on? Are you using MapReducev1 with CDH5.5?

Comment: I add the code ,I just want to test the example ---- use spark write to hbase, in **local**mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced such issue . It basically due to jar issue only.

[image: thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:]

Add the Jar file from Maven spark-core_2.10

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

After changing the Jar file
[image: After change]

Comment: Your problem is because of the scala version.I also have met this ,but I think  my problem is about hadoop version ,i have try many times,still no idea!

Comment: yes you need to provide right version of hadoop version .Are you using Cloudera hadoop .then try to include the maven from Cloudera.

Answer (score 1):

Oh,I have resolve this problem,add the maven dependency

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

the error disappear!